# How can I test if the OLS slope is different from a expected slope?

Tags: t-test, least-squares, linear-model

I am currently testing if an OLS slope is statistically different from a known, expected slope. I think I would need to do a one-sampled t-test but I am not exactly sure how. Specifically, is the degree of freedom also N-1 if I have N data points? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: If testing a slope an OLS model is appropriate, you can then test a hypothesis against any constant (by default 0, but it doesn't have to be).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OLS - Why coefficient Beta has Normal Distribution but not t-Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603210/ols-why-coefficient-beta-has-normal-distribution-but-not-t-distribution) My answer to the question gives all the necessary details to perform such a test.

Answer (score 0):

The degrees of freedom to use are $n-p$ (where $n$ is the number of data points, and $p$ the number of parameters), it relates to the distribution of the residuals which is used to estimate the distribution of the errors.

There are several questions that deal with this.

- [Why are the residuals in $\mathbb{R}^{n-p}$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515874/why-are-the-residuals-in-mathbbrn-p)
- [Why divide by $n-2$ for residual standard errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201352/why-divide-by-n-2-for-residual-standard-errors)

Also note that the problem of 'the distribution of the slope' might be more complicated when you consider

- Multiple variables like : [why does the same variable have a different slope when incorporated into a linear model with multiple x variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464170/)
- Correlations in the distribution of errors. (there are several ways how this can happen, an example is in time series: [Why do these time series appear to be dependent?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491794/why-do-these-time-series-appear-to-be-dependent)